# VB.net website conversion to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to convert an old website from VB to C#, I have been using Teleriks online code converter but I'm stuck on one particular area:

NavBar.ascx just contains some asp hyperlinks to form a navigation bar

The first line of it looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="NavBar.ascx.vb" Inherits="Nav_Bar" %>
```

NavBar.ascx.vb looks like:

```
Partial Class Nav_Bar
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
End Class
```

After putting this through the online converter and trying to fix the problem myself I'm left with:

NavBar.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"   CodeBehind="NavBar.ascx.cs" Inherits="Nav_Bar" %>
```

NavBar.ascx.cs

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

partial class Nav_Bar : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
}
```

When I try to build the project I get the error - Could not load type 'Nav_Bar'

Can someone please explain what the issue is here, I'm totally new to the .NET Framework and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After converting you have:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB"
```

Since you are now using C#, you need to update the language entry. If I remember correctly it should say C# instead of VB:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh you beat me by a few seconds. I will remove my answer.

Comment: A sign of an active community, even on a Sunday. :)